# variable in class name jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I can't set a variable name in a class in jade:

```
.flag_#{ session.locale } #{ session.locale }
```

I have:

```
<div class="flag_" >en</div>
```

And I'd like to have

```
<div class="flag_en" >en</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Try this (have not tested):

```
div(class="flag_#{ session.locale }") session.locale
```

Comment: Note that this also works if you have classes already in the Jade, like so: `.flag(class="flag_#{session.locale}") session.locale` => `<div class="flag flag_en_GB">en_GB</div>`

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 16):

As for pug@2.0.0-alpha3 works this way:

```
div(class="flag_" + session.locale) session.locale
```

Comment: check the version you are using - @karaxuna's solution doesn't work anymore on pug

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach:

```
mixin formButton(text, type, extra_classes)
    - var default_classes = 'btn btn-primary'
    if extra_classes
        - var classes = default_classes + ' ' + extra_classes
    else
        - var classes = default_classes

    if type
        button(class=classes type=type) !{text}
    else
        button(class=classes type="submit") !{text}
```

**Example 1:**

Usage:

```
+formButton('Text')
```

Result:

```
<button type="text" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Text</button>
```

**Example 2:**

Usage:

```
+formButton('Text', 'button')
```

Result:

```
<button type="text" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Text</button>
```

**Example 3:**

Usage:

```
+formButton('Text', 'button', 'extra-class')
```

Result:

```
<button type="text" class="btn btn-primary extra-class" type="button">Text</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [conditional statements](http://jade-lang.com/reference/conditionals/) to do this like

```
  if liked == true
    span.like.active
  else
    span.like
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
- const session = { locale: 'en' }
div(class=`flag_${session.locale}`) #{session.locale}

//- Just to show more options:

div(class=`flag_${session.locale}`)= session.locale
div(class=`flag_${session.locale}`) Current language is #{session.locale}
div(class=`flag_${session.locale}`)= `Current language is ${session.locale}`
```

Output (using Pug 2.0.4):

```html
<div class="flag_en">en</div>
<div class="flag_en">en</div>
<div class="flag_en">Current language is en</div>
<div class="flag_en">Current language is en</div>
```