# Jade template a class

Tags: javascript, pug

I'd like to use Jade to set the class of list item. For example, I'd like to pass a string 'foo' to the list class from a JSON object, `{'class': 'foo'}`:

```
<li class='foo'> blah </>
```

Using Jade, I'm trying to do something like this to set the class to foo:

`li = #class`

How can I template thus correctly in Jade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this answer: [variable in class name jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668881/variable-in-class-name-jade)

You should be able to do this:

```
li(class="#{ class }") blah
```