# pug/jade class names that start with a digit

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I'm new to professional Web Development (and especially Pug/Jade), and I was wondering if there was a way to use the short-form id/class names that start with a number.

i.e. `<div class="row">` is just `.row`

But I'm not quite sure how to do the same for divs with class names such as:

`<div class="row uniform 50%">` or `<div class="8u 12u$(small)">`.

I can just use `div(class="row uniform 50%")` but I was wondering if there was a neat way to doing this. Doing `.\-8u.\-12u$(xsmall)` doesn't give me errors but (of course) it doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: you can't make classes that starts with a number.

Comment: what if I wanted to call `<div class="6u">`? should I just use `div(class="6u")`?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be using a [Mixin](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html).

Here is an example of a mixin with a button https://stackoverflow.com/a/30823393/2235593